Slug Field in Django Model Not Including Related Tags on Save
I have the following save method in my Django model:
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    tags = Tag.objects.filter(office__id=self.id).values_list("name", flat=True)
    print("Tags")
    print(tags)

    location_work_override_id = self.location_work_override.id if self.location_work_override else ''
    location_work_id = self.contest.location_work_id if self.contest and self.contest.location_work_id else ''

    if not self.slug and tags:
        self.slug = slugify(
            f"{self.display_name}-{'-'.join(tags)}-{location_work_override_id}-{location_work_id}-{self.contest.short_name}-{self.contest.contest_number}"
        )
    elif not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(
            f"{self.display_name}-{location_work_override_id}-{location_work_id}-{self.contest.short_name}-{self.contest.contest_number}"
        )

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

The slug field is supposed to include related Tag names from a Tag model that has a ForeignKey to Office. However, when I create a new Office instance in the Django admin, the tags variable in the save method is always empty, even though I add the tags in the admin interface.
I suspect this is a timing issue because the save method of Office runs before the related Tag objects are saved.
My Questions:

How can I ensure that the Tag objects are saved before the save method of the Office model accesses them?
Is there a way to correctly populate the slug field with the tags in this scenario, preferably without relying on manual order of operations?


How did you specify an office value for the Tag that you created before the corresponding Office object was created? Chances are, you are creating the Office first and then creating the Tag. If that's the case, then just calling office.save() again should give you the desired slug.
